# TriangleException & NonStatic toString()

Tags: java

I'm writing a program that takes two triangles as instances & determines if they are illegal or not, and throws an exception if they are. My first issue is that I'm trying to throw a `TriangleException`, not an `Exception`. I'm sure I just need to change or add something somewhere so it will stop giving me an error in Eclipse.

My second issue is that I'm trying to use a `toString()` method to output the side dimensions of the illegal triangle when an `Exception` is thrown. It keeps telling me that I can't make a non-static reference with a call to `toString()`. I've looked online and tried some different possible solutions, but none of them seem to work.

I have included my two classes below:

```
public class TriangleException extends Object {

    private double side1;
    private double side2;
    private double side3;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            TriangleWithException t1 = new TriangleWithException(1.5, 2, 3);
            System.out.println("Perimeter for t1: " + t1.getPerimeter());
            System.out.println("Area for t1: " + t1.getArea());

            TriangleWithException t2 = new TriangleWithException(1,2,3);
            System.out.println("Perimeter for t2: " + t2.getPerimeter());
            System.out.println("Area for t2: " + t2.getArea());
        }
        catch (TriangleException e){
            System.out.println("\nIllegal Triangle!!!");
            System.out.println(toString()); // trying to print the three sides of the illegal triangle here
        }
    }

    public double getSide1() {
        return side1;
    }

    public double getSide2() {
        return side2;
    }

    public double getSide3() {
        return side3;
    }
}

public class TriangleWithException extends Object {

    double side1, side2, side3;

    public TriangleWithException(double d, double i, double j) throws Exception {
        side1 = d;
        side2 = i;
        side3 = j;

        if (side1 >= side2 + side3)
            throw new TriangleException();
        else if (side2 >= side1 + side3)
            throw new TriangleException();
        else if (side3 >= side2 + side1)
            throw new TriangleException();
    }

    public double getArea() {
        double var = (side1 + side2 + side3)/2;
        double area = (var*(var-side1)*(var-side2)*(var-side3));
        return Math.sqrt(area);
    }

    public double getPerimeter() {
        return (side1+side2+side3);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "\nSide 1 = " + this.side1 + "\nSide 2 = " + this.side2
            + "\nSide 3 = " + this.side3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should extend `Exception`, not `Object`. `Object` is not throwable. If you check the javadoc for `Exception`, you will in fact see that `Exception` itself implements `Throwable`.

Answer (score 0):

1. New Exceptions that you write should be subclassing `Exception`, not `Object`.
2. There should only be a single class marked public in a Java file. So if you are having both the classes in the single file, you need to revisit it.
3. `toString()` is not a static method i.e., a non-static method. So you need to invoke it using a reference of the object. So instead of just using `toString()`, change it to `e.toString()`.

```
catch (TriangleException e){
    System.out.println("\nIllegal Triangle!!!");
    System.out.println(e.toString()); // trying to print the three sides of the illegal triangle here
}
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation for the above code.

1. For implementing a custom exception, you need to extend the `Exception` class not the `Object` class.
2. The `TriangleException` class should care about the exception only. Nothing else.
3. You don't need any members in the `TriangleException` class for holding the sides.
4. The `TriangleWithException` with pass its reference, while throwing the exception. Which you set as the message in the `Exception` class by calling the `super()` constructor.
5. There should be a separate driver class for testing the functionality. Or you should the `TriangleWithException` class instead of the exception class.
6. You need not to extend the `Object` class separately. Every class by default extends it.
7. **Ideally**, constructor should not perform any validity checks. You should have a separate method `isValid()` for checking the validity of the Triangle.

```
public class TriangleException extends Exception {

  public TriangleException(TriangleWithException e) {
    super(e.toString());
  }
}

public class TriangleWithException {

  double side1, side2, side3;

  public TriangleWithException(double d, double i, double j) throws TriangleException {
    side1 = d;
    side2 = i;
    side3 = j;

    if (side1 >= side2 + side3)
      throw new TriangleException(this);
    else if (side2 >= side1 + side3)
      throw new TriangleException(this);
    else if (side3 >= side2 + side1)
      throw new TriangleException(this);
  }

  public double getArea() {
    double var = (side1 + side2 + side3)/2;
    double area = (var*(var-side1)*(var-side2)*(var-side3));
    return Math.sqrt(area);
  }

  public double getPerimeter() {
    return (side1+side2+side3);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "\nSide 1 = " + this.side1 + "\nSide 2 = " + this.side2
        + "\nSide 3 = " + this.side3;
  }
}    

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    try {
      TriangleWithException t1 = new TriangleWithException(1.5, 2, 3);
      System.out.println("Perimeter for t1: " + t1.getPerimeter());
      System.out.println("Area for t1: " + t1.getArea());

      TriangleWithException t2 = new TriangleWithException(1,2,3);
      System.out.println("Perimeter for t2: " + t2.getPerimeter());
      System.out.println("Area for t2: " + t2.getArea());
    }
    catch (TriangleException e){
      System.out.println("\nIllegal Triangle!!!");
      System.out.println(e.getMessage()); // trying to print the three sides of the illegal triangle here
    }
  }    
}
```

**Output:**

```
Perimeter for t1: 6.5
Area for t1: 1.3331705629813464

Illegal Triangle!!!

Side 1 = 1.0
Side 2 = 2.0
Side 3 = 3.0
```